# github raw drawable folders

Tags: github, git-commit

How can I ignore exclude `raw` and `drawable` folders from github commits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `.gitignore` in your `/res` folder with the following contents:

```
raw/
drawable/
```

Comment: in the project folder i also have a gitignore with bin/ on it but when i try to make commit all the bin files appear

Comment: Make sure its .gitignore and not gitignore.

Comment: it is the github default file

Answer (score 0):

just add the .gitignore file with /raw and /drawable

Comment: so i have to do something like this?#################
## Eclipse
#################

*.pydevproject
.project
.metadata
bin/
tmp/
*.tmp
*.bak
*.swp
*~.nib
local.properties
.classpath
.settings/
.loadpath
/raw